# Are @synchronized blocks guaranteed to release their locks?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Assume these are instance methods and `-run` is called.

Is the lock on `self` released by the time `-run` returns?

```
...
- (void)dangerous {
    @synchronized (self) {
        [NSException raise:@"foo" format:@"bar"];
    }
}

- (void)run {
    @try { [self dangerous]; }
    @catch (NSException *ignored) {}
}
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `@synchronized(obj) { code }` block is effectively equivalent to

```
NSRecursiveLock *lock = objc_fetchLockForObject(obj);
[lock lock];
@try {
    code
}
@finally {
    [lock unlock];
}
```

though any particular aspect of this is really just implementation details. But yes, a `@synchronized` block is guaranteed to release the lock no matter how control exits the block.

Comment: objc_fetchLockForObject(code) should be objc_fetchLockForObject(obj), I suppose

Comment: I was hoping for this level of detail (and thought this was probably the case). Thx!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is.

Lock on `self` will be released after your process goes out from `@synchronized (self) {}` block.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the lock is released when -dangerous returns (even via exception). @synchronized adds an implicit exception handler to release the mutex.