# Confusion about locks

Tags: ios, multithreading, synchronization, nsmutablearray, mutex

There is one thing I am not sure about when it comes to locks. I've read http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW16 but one thing I am not sure about; does @synchronize (or just mutex in general) protect only a section of code (say inside a method) or lock the entire object as a whole?

For example, two threads working on these methods, which modify an array;

```
@synthesize m_myMutableArray;

-(void)threadA
{
    @synchronized(m_myMutableArray) {
         [m_myMutableArray removeAllObjects];
    }
}

-(void)threadB
{
    NSInteger asdf = 1;
    @synchronized(m_myMutableArray) {
         [m_myMutableArray addObject:asdf];

}
```

Does @synchronized not do anything because they are two separate blocks of code, or is it the same mutex being locked in both methods, meaning m_myMutableArray is threadsafe?

Thanks

Comment: Related: [Are @synchronized blocks guaranteed to release their locks?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7735799/557219) Kevin’s answer should answer your question as well: it is the same mutex so long as the object being pointed to by `m_myMutableArray` is the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does @synchronized lock/unlock in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215330/how-does-synchronized-lock-unlock-in-objective-c)

Comment: Do I also have to use the @synchronized directive every time I am about to access the m_myMutablearray? For example, if threadB did not use the synchronized directive, would it still block if threadA locked it before?

Comment: Yes, you should use it whenever you access the array. No, if threadB didn’t use `@synchronized`, it wouldn’t block if threadA locked it before, which is problematic since `NSMutableArray` isn’t thread-safe.

Comment: That would mean quite alot of locks due to the array being used at several places. If threadA was the mainthread, could I simply use performSelectorOnMainThread whenever threadB needed to access it,and they would queue up in the same thread and be safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "argument" to `@synchronized` is a so-called *token* or key so you can have different locked sections. They only block each other when they have the same token. The object themselves are not "locked".

So if you have two `@synchronized(foo)` and two `@synchronized(bar)`, the *foo* sections block each other but will not block the *bar* sections.

If possible, you should [avoid `@synchronized` as it's very slow](http://perpendiculo.us/?p=133), due to its dynamic nature.

Comment: if threadA is the mainthread, could I use performSelectorOnMainThread for all interfering operations in threadB?

Comment: You mean, to avoid locking altogether? Depending on what you want to do this is an option. But note that if you set *waitUntilDone:YES* then threadB will block until the main has finished its current run loop iteration and can then perform your selector. Most of the time is way slower than locking.

Comment: If I do not waitUntillDone (it is callbacks updating a UI elements like a ListView) is it a good solution?

Comment: Yes, it's OK. I do this a lot as well.